# Given a non-empty array of integers nums, every element appears twice except for one. Find that single one using hashing

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, unique

For the input {4,1,2,1,2} , it is showing the value 2 instead of 4  ,this is my code ,when i took thesame input in my pc ,it is showing correct answer,but in leetcode it is showing incorrect

```
 int singleNumber(vector<int>& nums) {
        int n=nums.size();
        int k=2*n;
        int hash[k];
        int s;
        if (n==1)
            s=nums[0];
        else
        {
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            if(nums[i]>0)
            hash[nums[i]]++;
            else
            {
              nums[i]=nums[i]+1000;
                  hash[nums[i]]++;
            }
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<k;i++)
        {
            if(hash[i]==1)
              s=i;  
        }
        }     
        
        return s;
        
    }
};
```

Comment: There are numerous problems. You're not using hashing, you use variables that are uninitialized, and you can access arrays out of bounds.

Comment: I don't see why anyone would use hashing for this, unless they believe that "hashing" is the same as "exclusive or".

Comment: Technically you can't have a "non-empty array". Arrays and vectors are not the same.

Comment: Might not be the solution, but `int hash[k];` is no valid C++, but a compiler-specific extension and is likeley to cause problems for larger `k`. Use a vector instead.